# How did this mean average 'trick' work, or didn't it?

Tags: statistics, average, means

This encounter sparked my interest in maths around 12 years ago whilst in primary school and I just remembered it recently and I have no idea how it was done.

Our teacher showed the classroom (around 30 students) a jar full of plastic bears and stated that the number within the jar was between 700-750 and we should all estimate individually how many bears are within the jar. Once we had made our estimates, he asked us to calculate the collective mean average. After we had written our worked-out means on a sticky note he revealed the number in the jar and it had matched the mean average I had written down.

Here is the nuance: Given that out of a class of ~30 probably ~9-year-olds, the task was done by hand (leading to errors), and I was the only one with the "correct" solution was this by chance in that we had all done it wrong or was I the only person who had the correct mean and thus, had worked out the correct number of bears within the jar just from our group collective estimates alone?

Comment: It is not possible to conclude the exact number in the jar.  If you take a mean of student guesses, the mean will most likely be a noninteger.  If the mean is an integer and/or close to the true number in the jar, that is a coincidence.  If you knew something about the true guesses being independent and unbiased then you can argue something about law of large numbers.  But there is no reason that guesses should be unbiased (that is, no reason to have the expected guess be the exact number in the jar).

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot Michael, I suspected as much. Have a great week.

Comment: Though $700-750$ is a fairly narrow range.  It is possible that there are typical guesses and the teacher started by adjusting the number towards the average of those

Comment: @Henry I recall there being an envelope with the true number sealed inside which he had left unopened until the grand reveal at the end. Unless you mean he had conducted this experiment before and used the typical guesses from the prior. That could have been the case, who knows.

Comment: I intended the second - though being a conjuror is another possibility

Comment: What's a "collective mean average"? I guess you just mean "mean" or "average". I am glad that your teacher sparked your interest in mathematics, but I think he was either doing a conjuring trick or had a different punchline up his sleeve for the case when no-one got the exact answer.

Comment: This is the idea behind [The Wisdom of the Crowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisdom_of_the_crowd) and [Prediction Markets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_market): that estimates made by averaging many individual estimates are often surprisingly good (but not necessarily exact).

Comment: @awkward Thanks a lot!